# Why is this Java program 1000 times faster than its Ada equivalent?

Tags: java, ada

I have two programs that simply loop a billion times and increment an integer. I am timing both of the operations and comparing the two results. For the Ada program, I am using the GNAT FSF compiler. Both programs are run on Windows. I have also tried running multiple of each code and averaging the measured duration, which shows the same result.

There are two things that I expect are happening, either my Ada program is not written properly (I am very new to the language), or that it is written properly, but the Java compiler is doing something to the code that I am not aware of.

Here is the Ada program:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar; use Ada.Calendar;

procedure Main is
    c : Integer := 1;

    startTime, endTime : Time;
    milliS : Duration;
begin
    startTime := Clock;
    while c <= 1000000000 loop
        c := c + 1;
    end loop;

    endTime := Clock;
    milliS := (endTime - startTime) * 1000;

    put_line("Runtime = " & Duration'Image(milliS) & " milliseconds.");
end Main;
```

and the Java code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = 1;
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        while (c<=1000000000) {
            c = c + 1;
        }

        long stop = System.nanoTime();

        float duration = (float) ((start - stop)/1000000.0);
        System.out.println(duration);
    }
}
```

Ada compiles straight to machine code, so I expected it to be faster than the Java program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java JIT compiler is smart enough to realize that the loop can be optimized away. And it does that.

If you modified the Java version to print out the value of `c` right at the end, you would get an execution time that is roughly comparable to the (unoptimized) Ada version.  If the value for `c` is used, the loop can't be optimized away<sup>1</sup>.

> Ada compiles straight to machine code, so I expected it to be faster than the Java program.

The Java JIT compiler compiles to machine code too, but not immediately.

---

<sup>1 - Until we get a *omniscient* JIT compiler that realizes that we don't pay any attention to the output :-)</sup>

Comment: Note: I did not attempt to reproduce the OP's results.

Answer (score 3):

I can't replicate your problem.

I built your program with

```
$ gnatmake -gnata -gnato -fstack-check -gnat12 -gnatyO -gnatv -gnati1 -gnatf -gnatn -O3 main.adb
gcc-6 -c -gnata -gnato -fstack-check -gnat12 -gnatyO -gnatv -gnati1 -gnatf -gnatn -O3 main.adb

GNAT 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright 1992-2016, Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Compiling: main.adb
Source file time stamp: 2018-08-01 08:20:21
Compiled at: 2018-08-01 10:20:30
 19 lines: No errors
gnatbind-6 -x main.ali
gnatlink-6 main.ali -fstack-check -O3
$
```

Then I ran the program using `time` to check the execution time:

```
$ time ./main
Runtime =  0.002000000 milliseconds.
./main  0,00s user 0,00s system 82% cpu 0,005 total
$
```

If you don't optimise, then an Ada compiler will attempt to ensure that you have as close match as possible between source text and machine code as possible, to make it easy to certify that your executable does the right thing. - And in that case you should of course get 1_000_000_000 iterations in your loop.

Comment: Running the optimizations posted here returned the same result for me. However, I am likely not doing something right, as I stated, I am new to the language. My main goal with this test was to determine if Ada gave me a noticeable speed increase, assuming that both programs perform the same general calculations, but I didn't consider the fact that the JIT compiler would remove my for loop, which I would rather that it didn't...

Comment: @user3117351 If you don't want the JIT compiler to remove the loop, you must have it do something that passes for meaningful work--and have the Ada implementation do the same thing.

Comment: Should also note that the JIT compiler is doing the (objectively) right thing.  1) The goal of the JIT optimizer is to make the code run as fast as possible in a production setting.  It can't "read your intentions" ... to figure out that this is not a production setting.  2) Even when benchmarking, one should be aiming to replicate production performance.  That is normally the point of benchmarking.  3) Micro-benchmarks that do artificial things in an attempt to measure performance of language constructs need to be carefully written .... in any PL ... because of optimization effects.

Comment: This no-optimization behavior is actually specific to GNAT. Most other Ada compilers do some optimization, even at their lowest optimization settings.